Data protocol in helicopter's ARINC 717
I am presently doing a project where in I want to transfer certain aircraft parameters (helicopter) to a ground station where I would like to monitor them (establish a data link). I have thought of passively tapping them from the data bus between DIU unit and FDR which uses ARINC 717 protocol. Could I have some guidance on how to go about this?
